# NoSQL or SQL for Data Structure

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, database-design, nosql

I'm building an app, and this is my first time working with databases. I went with MongoDB because originally I thought my data structure would be fitting for it. After more research, I've become a bit lost in all the possible ways I could structure my data, and which of those would be best for performance vs best for my DB type (currently MongoDB, but could change to PostgreSQL). Here are all my data structures and iterations:

*Note: I understand that the "Payrolls" collection is somewhat redundant in the below example. It's just there as something to represent the data hierarchy in this hypothetical.*

**Original Data Structure**

[image: MongoDB Original Data Schema]

The structure here is consistent with what NoSQL is good at, quickly fetching everything in a single document. However, I intend for my employee object to hold lots of data, and I don't want that to encroach on the document size limit as a user continues to add employees and data to those employees, so I split them into a separate collection and tied them together using reference (object) IDs:

**Second Data Structure**

[image: Employees split to second collection]

It wasn't long after that I wanted to be able to manipulate the clients, locations, departments, and employees all independent of one another, but still maintain their relationships, and I arrived at this iteration of my data structure:

**Third and Current Data Structure**

[image: final, decentralized data structure]

It was at this point that I began to realize I had been shifting away from the NoSQL philosophy. Now, instead of executing one query against one collection in a database (1st iteration), or executing one query with a follow-up population (2nd iteration), I was now doing 4 queries in parallel when grabbing my data, despite all the data being related tied to each other.

**My Questions**

Is my first data structure suitable to continue with MongoDB? If so, how do I compensate for the document size limit in the event the employees field grows too large?

Is my second data structure more suitable to continue with MongoDB? If so, how can I manipulate the fields independently? Do I create document schemas/models for each field and query them by model?

Is my third data structure still suitable for MongoDB, or should I consider a move to a relational database with this level of decentralized structure? Does this structure allow me any more freedom *or* ease of access to manipulate my data than the others?

Comment: Based on the questions you are asking, the amount of thought you have put into organizing your data, and the progression you have followed through your designs, now may be a very good time for you to spend an hour or two finding and reviewing introductory material about relational databases. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, but I will answer by saying that MongoDB should be able to handle your current data structure without too much trouble.  The maximum document size for a BSON Mongo document is 16MB (q.v. [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)).  This is quite a lot of text, and it is probably unlikely that, e.g., an employee would need 16MB of storage.

In the event that you need a single transaction per object to occupy *more* than the 16MB BSON maximum, you may use GridFS.  GridFS uses special collections (`files` and `chunks`) which do not have any storage limit (other than the limit of maximum database size).  With GridFS, you may write objects of any size, and MongoDB will accommodate the operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I suppose my follow-up question for a bit more clarity is to which data structure above you're referring to as sufficient, or are all 3 appropriate?

Comment: Well I don't like the first one, because it is a single JSON for the company, containing all employees.  Just because you're using a JSON store (Mongo) doesn't mean you still can't try to have a semi-relational setup with your data.  The 3rd version (your current model) is more along those lines.